# What size screws should I use to fasten these shelves together?

Tags: screws

I'm assembling shelving units as shown in the provided image, where I need to secure the vertical boards to the horizontal ones. My plan is to use three screws at both the top and bottom ends of each vertical piece to accomplish this.

Considering the wood is 3/4" thick sapele, would screws that are 1-1/4" in length be sufficient for a strong connection without risking them poking through the opposite side of the vertical pieces? I'm a bit nervous that I might drill at a slight angle and end up driving a screw through the side of one of the uprights.

Edit: Here's a link to the article where these shelves are found: https://blog.lostartpress.com/2021/07/05/covington-mechanical-library-shelves/

[image]

Comment: *"I'm a bit nervous that I might drill at a slight angle and end up driving a screw through the side of one of the uprights."* There's a neat trick (very old) for guarding against this and that's to drill viewing along the line of screws — we're not great at seeing a tilt towards or away from us but very good at seeing a lean to left or right. Any tilt in line with the width of the uprights doesn't matter unless the screws are too close to an edge :-) Re. screw length with 3 per joint honestly this should be perfectly fine (that's A LOT of screws) but if you did go with longer screws [contd]

Comment: ....it would allow you to drop the number to 2 per joint, which will save a heap of drilling. Remember to drill properly sized clearance and pilot holes! And countersinks/counterbores as well needless to say.

Comment: Thanks @Graphus, I ended up buying 1-5/8" screws, do you think 2 per edge (4 per upright) is sufficient? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0017354FU?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

Comment: Trim head screws don’t have as much holding power as normal #8. If it was me, I’d use 3+3 of those.

Comment: A separate design consideration you should address is the tendency the overall unit may have to lean (in either direction) so it should be anchored to the wall at the end or behind near the top to secure it when it is fully loaded.

Comment: I think you'll have to go with what's comfortable for you here rather than take another person's read on what will be sufficient. I presume you'll be building this up in height yes? One thing you could try is build up 2-3 layers, using two screws per edge (with the screws positioned as though a third would be in the middle) and check how solid it seems. If there's *any* play that concerns you by all means install the third screw for peace of mind..... it's rare to regret overbuilding something :-) However, do remember that one of the things about this and similar pieces is that they're [contd]

Comment: ...not conventional furniture, and hence don't need to be built as though they were. Some of the factors that one *must* build for in freestanding items, is that it will be moved around (usually by dragging across the floor, maybe even across carpet), it has to self-support in case of a bump or knock etc. Something firmly anchored to the wall by many L-brackets on the other hand isn't subject to those requirements and can be constructed a little more lightly *IF* desired.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use at least 1-1/2" and 2" would seem more natural. The forces acting on the screw aren't that substantial as long as you have it extremely well anchored to the wall using L brackets. ("Several L brackets" as understood by me, is nowhere near enough. I'd have at least 16 -- two per shelf, and you could happily go to 24. "Many" was the phrase in the original article.) If you haven't anchored it to the wall properly, no amount or length of screw will save you.